# How to delete a record in VB.net with Access database?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, ms-access

I am a beginner so I followed a tutorial on YouTube and made a program in VB.net using Windows Form that connects to an Access database. The program works, it can move to Previous record, Next record, Add new record and Save. However, the Delete button doesn't work.

I have tried searching for solutions and it was mentioned that I needed to have a Primary Key in the Access database or it wouldn't create a Delete command. So, I set a Primary Key then ran the program but Delete still doesn't work.

I've read that I need to configure the TableAdapter Configuration Wizard but they didn't specify on what exactly I should do. I tried messing around a bit and when I clicked on the Properties of the Table Adapter, I now see a DeleteCommand. However, I'm not sure of what to do with it or how to make it work.

This is what the delete button does

```
Private Sub DeleteBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DeleteBtn.Click

        PatientRecordsBindingSource.RemoveCurrent()
    End Sub
```

And this is what the save button does:

```
Private Sub SaveBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SaveBtn.Click
        On Error GoTo SaveErr
        PatientRecordsBindingSource.EndEdit()
        PatientRecordsTableAdapter.Update(DatabaseDataSet.PatientRecords)
        MessageBox.Show("Ok")
SaveErr:
        Exit Sub
```

So, I run the program and I can add and save new records in the table. But when I select a record from the table and then click the Delete button, it only deletes the record on the program. When I check the Access file, the supposedly deleted record is still there. But then I ran the program again and the record I tried to delete is back in the table, like nothing happened.

EDIT: I created a new Access Database file, made sure I assigned a Primary Key then tried it on a new form. It worked, but I am still wondering if I can still fix my problem with the old form.

Comment: What value is returned by that call to `Update`?

Comment: What do you mean? Sorry, I'm not familiar with the terms.

Comment: Looks like you are loading database data to DataSet, then binding that to something? (depending how your data is organized you could use something simpler, like a DataTable). If you data is a car, you only need one parking spot and not the whole garage for it, that kind of thing.

Comment: I use this code: Me.PatientRecordsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DatabaseDataSet.PatientRecords)

Comment: I used Binding Source, drag and dropped the Data (Details and Data Grid View) into the form then I use my own buttons for the Previous, Next, Add, Save, Delete

Comment: *"I'm not familiar with the terms"*. Then you ought to get familiar. There's nothing not completely basic there.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood correctly but when you mean value returned, do you mean like what exactly is being updated? If so, then the value being returned is the new record/s that the user has input through the program that are being saved into the PatientRecords table of Database. Again, I apologize if my question is stupid.

Comment: "What value is returned" means that `.Update` is really a Function. Functions return a value. In this case the returned value is an Integer, the number of rows affected. To answer @jmcilhinney 's question you could write `Dim retVal = PatientRecordsTableAdapter.Update(DatabaseDataSet.PatientRecords)` The value returned is in the variable retVal.

Comment: `On Error GoTo SaveErr` should not be used in new code. We have `Try...Catch...Finally` for exception handling now.